# Stored procedure to replace a string with another in an entire database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure to change a string in an entire database... after a lot of searching I have come up with this procedure, but it gives an error. The procedure is:

```
BEGIN

declare t,c varchar(100);

declare TABLES cursor for SELECT table_name, column_name
                                    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
                                    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='MY_DATABSE';

declare exit handler for 1329 begin end;
open tables;
looping: loop 
fetch tables into t,c;
SET @s1= CONCAT('UPDATE ', 
              'MY_DATABASE', '.', t, ' SET ',
              c, ' = replace(', c,', \'', old, '\'', ' , ', '\'', new, '\')');

     PREPARE stmt FROM @s1;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
end loop;
close tables;
END
```

And the error when calling the procedure with any parameter is the well known 1064 error in syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column_to_update(c) = replace(column_to_update(c), 'old' , 'new')' at line 1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "it gives an error" and "the well known 1064 error in syntax" are not valid descriptions of the problem you're having. What is the **exact error message** you're seeing? Posting a bunch of SQL and saying "it gives a syntax error" is meaningless. If you want help here, you need to be **specific** about the problem you're having. We can't see your screen or read your mind from here. We can only use the information you provide us.

Comment: apparentry some back-quotes were the missing piece. i had to place my t and c from @s1 into back-quotes and the procedure is working